# Creating month and year date using dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a date-month-year picker, in the image below, using a dropdown, I'm using flutter , should there be a control or should I write my own, and how do I get started? Thank you

[image]

Comment: DatePicker, and CupertinoDatePicker.

Comment: You can check pub.dev for some datepickers that are closer to what you want. Some may even offer customisations. Flutter has builtin ones you can use too link those @RandalSchwartz listed

Answer (score 3):

use `datepicker_dropdown` packages
https://pub.dev/packages/datepicker_dropdown

***pubspec.yaml***

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  datepicker_dropdown: ^0.0.7+1
```

```
import 'package:datepicker_dropdown/datepicker_dropdown.dart';

DropdownDatePicker(
                  inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))), // optional
                  isDropdownHideUnderline: true, // optional
                  isFormValidator: true, // optional
                  startYear: 1900, // optional
                  endYear: 2022, // optional
                  width: 10, // optional
                  selectedDay: 14, // optional
                  selectedMonth: 10, // optional
                  selectedYear: 1993, // optional
                  onChangedDay: (value) => print('onChangedDay: $value'),
                  onChangedMonth: (value) => print('onChangedMonth: $value'),
                  onChangedYear: (value) => print('onChangedYear: $value'),
                ),
```